# How can i solve this: params is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using this function to find users, which i am using `.require` only worked when i sent both or at least one parameter but if i send empty i got errors, It should not be mandatory to send parameters

```
def find_params
   params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
end
```

if i send the name or age i will work, but if i send nothing i am getting this error

```
params is missing
```

if i send empty like this:

`{}`  or `null` it should work correctly returning all the users

or should not i use this to search users?

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
```

might i have to user like this?

```
params[:name] and params[:age]
```

i am working with reactjs
i am sending the payload liket this:

```
{name:"ed", age:"12", skin:"black", weight: "180lbs", height:"183"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails' [`StrongParameters`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) were built for a very specific use:

> It provides an interface for protecting attributes from end-user assignment. This makes Action Controller parameters forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignment until they have been explicitly enumerated.

That means when you use the `params` just to read from the database, then there is no need (and hardly any advantage) to use `StrongParameters`.

Instead, I would just use the `params` directly in the controller like this:

```
def index
  @users = User
    .filter_by(:name, params.dig(:person, :name))
    .filter_by(:age, params.dig(:person, :age))

  # ...
end
```

And to make this work you will need to define an `filter_by` scope in your `app/models/user.rb`:

```
scope :filter_by, -> (attr, value) { where(attr => value) if value.present? }
```

Comment: This is a scenario that Strong Parameters handles just fine. You just need to use `.fetch(:person, {})` instead of `require`.

Comment: Yeah @max, but what is the point of using `StrongParams` in this scenario. I see not benefit in doing that.

Comment: The benefit is really that its a pretty good generic mechanism for parameters whitelisting and that its something already used in the app. Its basically a hash on steriods backed by a simple DSL.  While there might not be a mass assignment vulnerabily you still don't want a malicous user to be able to search by any column (and thus guess their existence).

Comment: When it is just about DSL then you could use `params.require(:people).slice(:age, :name)` or `params.fetch(:people, {}).slice(:age, :name)` and not care about permitted attributes.

Comment: "Permitted attributes" as I see it is really just there to protect the programmer against their own lazyness/ignorance. Its just a simple attribute that causes `ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment` to raise an error. The general API is still geniunely useful for a lot of use cases and I have used it for example to slice complex API responses. I think a lot of people forget that you can just create instances of Parameters with a hash and play around with them and that its not some scary magical component.

Comment: @spickermann please take a look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466109/why-i-am-getting-this-error-must-be-exist-card

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using `ActionController::Parameters#require` is to cause your create/update method to bail early if the parameter you expect to be a hash isn't sent at all since there is no point in proessing the request further and this prevents a potential uncaught nil error.

If you want to allow a key to be null use `#fetch` instead:

```ruby
params.fetch(:person, {})
      .permit(:name, :age)
```

`#fetch` allows you to pass a second key which is the default value and it returns a new ActionController::Parameters instance.
But it looks like you're actually sending flat parameters which are not nested in which case you don't need fetch either:

```ruby
params.permit(:name, :age)
```

Note that Rails by default has parameters wrapping turned on for JSON requests and both will very likely work.

Comment: please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466109/why-i-am-getting-this-error-in-factory-must-be-exist-card

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Find User`

Routes.rb

```
   get "search_user", to: "users#search_user"
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
  def search_user
    @users = User.search(params[:name], params[:age], params[:skin], params[:weight], params[:height]) // search name or age
    // you can use byebug  to check @users
  end
```

models/user.rb

```
  def self.search(name, age, skin, weight, height)
    if name.blank? & age.blank? & skin.blank? & weight.blank? & hight.blank?
      all
    else  
      where('name LIKE ? OR age LIKE ? OR skin LIKE ? OR weight LIKE ? OR height LIKE ?', "%#{name}%", "%#{age}%", "%#{skin}%", "%#{weight}%", "%#{height}%")
    end
  end
```

=> This is my way which i used. Hope to help you.

Comment: this params[:search] does not exist

Comment: Please share you code in html file

Comment: You want to search `name and age` or only `name or age` ?. Let's me know. I will update my answer.

Comment: name and age but sometime age does not exist in db

Comment: Okie you try check  again

Comment: if key_search.blank? what does mean this?

Comment: should not be AND here name LIKE ? OR age LIKE ?

Comment: Sorry. I updated my answer.

Comment: what could be happen if could there is three or four or five parameters name, age, skin, weight, height

Comment: Can you add friend to resolve this issue ? i will support

Comment: with this payload {name:"ed", age:"12", skin:"black", weight: "180lbs", height:"183"} the comparations with .present will be complicated

Comment: I updated my answer again. I think you use `OR`. you try again. And If you don't search name, you default in FE ex: {name: ' ' , age: 20, skin: ' ' , weight: ' ', height: ' ' }, the same other fields.