# Why i am getting this error in Factory: must be exist card? how can i solved it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

Only i want to create a 'post' but i am getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: let!(:post) { FactoryBot.create(:post, company_id: company.id, card_id: card.id) } 
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
        Validation failed: must be exist card
```

the model of post is:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_title, :sub_title, :email, presence: true
  belongs_to :card
  delegate :max, to: :card
end
```

and card:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  include Discard::Model
end
```

factories:

```
factory :post do
    first_title { Faker::Name.name }
    sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email}
    card_id {}
  end
```

factory for card:

```
factory :card do
  company_id {}
end
```

Comment: Probably because you need whatever a card is. Did you mean to pass in `card_id`?

Comment: Tengential, but might want to clean up that validation message--it's a little awkward.

Comment: Good, but does `Post` actually have the `Card` relation id spelled `car_id`?! Or does it **actually** follow a reasonable naming convention and it's called `card_id`, which you're not providing?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a validation in Card model file, that enforces the presence of a field  (like `presence: true` or `numericality: {only_integer: true}` without an `allow_blank: true` etc ..)  you have forgotten to pass to your Card Factory .

Comment: Dave says there is a typo in your code , you have written : `car_id: card.id` But maybe the typo is only here, not in your actual code

Comment: Add the related factories in the question too, maybe they are not well defined. Another idea: maybe you forgot to create a `company` object before the `card` object: `let!(:company) { FactoryBot.create(:company) }` ?

Comment: Please share more details: What do those models look like, their associations and validations. What do the factories look like? What does the whole test look like? And please share to full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: @spickermann help me please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75540469/how-can-i-create-an-object-inside-of-other-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the response from the other question:

```
factory :card do
  association :company, factory: :company
end

factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email}

  transient do
    company_id { FactoryBot.create(:company).id }
  end

  after(:build) do |post, evaluator|
    card = FactoryBot.create(:card, company_id: evaluator.company_id)
    post.card = card
  end
end

let(:company) { FactoryBot.create :company }
let!(:post) { FactoryBot.create(:post, company_id: company.id }
let(:card) { post.card }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your factories are not well defined. This should be the first thing to make sure it works fine. Try to define "associations" like this:

```
factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  card
end
```

Or:

```
factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  card { FactoryBot.create(:card) }
end
```

Or also, you can try using the `association` macro:

```
factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email}
  association :card, factory: :card
end
```