# How can i create an object inside of other object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I want to create a 'post' and a 'card', but to create an card its necessary have company_id

```
factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  company_id {}
  card { FactoryBot.create(:card, company_id: company_id) }
end
```

But i am getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `company_id' for #<FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner:0x00007f629fb1b260
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the `company_id` in both records? When `Post belongs_to :company` and `Card belongs_to :post` then there is no need to have a `company_id` on `Post` too. Instead, you could just call `post.card.company` or could add `delegate :company, to: :post` to `Card` and then call `post.company`.

Comment: @spickermann i cant change the models, designs

Comment: But are those model association properly set up, and will both records always have the same `company_id` or are there cases in which the `company_id` might be different?

Comment: @spickermann my team said that the associations are ok, only i have to work in factory of specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally if your test needs to create a well defined ocntext for it self and not rely on the factories behaviour, so you should call the factories passing the associated objects as a param for each factory call.

But if you really want to achieve this using the id you can use transient attributes.

Using the `card` object:

```
factory :company do
  # whatever you need here
end

factory :card do
  company
end

factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  card
end

let(:company) { FactoryBot.create :company }
let(:card) { FactoryBot.create(:card, company: company) }
let!(:post) { FactoryBot.create(:post, card: card) }
```

Using the transient attribute:

```
# factory:
factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email }

  transient do
    company_id { FactoryBot.create(:company).id }
  end

  after(:build) do |post, evaluator|
    card = FactoryBot.create(:card, company_id: evaluator.company_id)
    post.card = card
  end
end
# spec:
let(:company) { FactoryBot.create :company }
let!(:post) { FactoryBot.create(:post, company_id: company.id) }
```

Update: I have added a code for the factories in the first example

Comment: i am getting this error:       
 ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
       PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "company_id" of relation "cards" violates not-null constraint
       DETAIL:

Comment: My bad, when calling the card factory inside the `after(:build)` I am missing the keyword argument: `card = FactoryBot.create(:card, company_id: evaluator.company_id)`

Comment: Fixed the code on the answer

Comment: @FelipeSadoyana now i am getting this error:  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: card must exist

Comment: Give me some minutes, I will run the code myself

Comment: @whatl your spec code is calling the factories the same as I did?

Comment: locally its working, but in github actions no, my problem is in github actions

Comment: Being a github actions specific error makes it hard for me to debugg but try using `before(:create)` instead of `after(:build)` as there could potentially be an issue with the execution order

Comment: but i think there is this incoherence: first we are creating a company in spec `let(:company) { FactoryBot.create :company } ` and we are passing at 'post' like this: `let!(:post) { FactoryBot.create(:post, company_id: company.id) }` but in the factory we are creating other one `transient do company_id { FactoryBot.create(:company).id } end` it should be the same `company_id`

Comment: A transient attribute is a temporary attribute on the factory that is only evaluated and then discard after the factroy build/creation is done, the code in brackets on factories are defaults for the attributes and are only evaluated in case the attribute is not explictly passed. `company_id { FactoryBot.create(:company).id }` means that a comany factory will be called and company_id will receive the created object id in case, and only if, you call the post factory without passing a company_id. SO calling the company factory before the post factory and passing the id should be fine

Comment: @whatl in any case I have added a detailed code for the first approach in case you want to try it, as it is a lot cleaner and conceptually correct

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `FactoryBot` much in the past. But when looking into the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) then I would try this:

```
factory :post do
  first_title { Faker::Name.name }
  sub_title { Faker::Name.name }
  email { Faker::Internet.email }

  company
  card { association :card, country: country }
end
```

Or you can add a callback to your `Card` model to set the `country` automatically to the country of the associated post, like this:

```
# in app/models/card.rb
before_validation :set_country

private

def set_country
  self.country = post&.country
end
```